# Differnece between setText(null/"") in java swing?

Tags: java

Is there any difference between:

```
textField.setText("");
```

and

```
textField.setText(null);
```

when i call it from a JTextField?

Comment: Have you tried it? Do you see any difference?

Comment: Why not read the documentation of the method before anything?

Answer (score 4):

Straight from the docs:

> Sets the text of this TextComponent to the specified text. **If the text is null or empty**, has the effect of simply deleting the old text.

source: [Java 7 API Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: thanks, atleast one of two guys who just can answer a question instead of randomly downvote!

Comment: The reason your question was down-voted was because the answer is something that is easily found in the documentation. Whenever you have a question like this, you should always look there *first* before asking your question here.

Answer (score 1):

From the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.java#JTextComponent.setText%28java.lang.String%29) :

> Sets the text of this TextComponent to the specified text. If the text
> is null or empty, has the effect of simply deleting the old text.

So no, there won't be any difference between both.

Answer (score 0):

You won't see any differce, but this will give a null pointer exception:

```
if(textField.getText().equals("text"))
```

Because getText is null and can't equal a string.